# Support for SHA256withECDSAinP1363Format signing algorithm in hashicorp vault transit engine

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp, spring-vault, transit

We have created a encryption key of type ecdsa-p256 and We have successfully created signature with SHA256withECDSA and public key received while creation.

But want to use signing algorithm SHA256withECDSAinP1363Format .

So Please check and let us know if the vault transit engine supports signing using the SHA256withECDSAinP1363Format signing algorithm which creates a sign message with size below 65 bytes which is also named as raw ANSI X9.62 ECDSA or FIX length 64 byte with ECDSA.

Comment: Have you checked the Vault documentation?

Comment: Yes , in vault documentation nothing is mentioned related to this SHA256withECDSAinP1363Format signing algorithm

Comment: That suggests that it probably isn't supported, then?